# Setup proxy in Firefox browser via marionette driver

Tags: selenium, proxy, webdriver, firefox-marionette

Firefox 47 and above do not support Selenium Webdriver. I tried to use a Marionette driver to start my tests via Firefox.

But my settings in firefox-profile (proxy must set to `network.proxy.type = 4`, auto-detect) is no longer applied to Firefox config (Firefox opens but all settings set by default) and my tests do not work without the right PROXY configuration.

How can I setup proxy in Firefox browser via a Marionette driver?

Answer (score 1):

The old tricks with firefoxProfile or Proxy class do not work any more. All you have to do is pass through requiredCapabilities a JSON with the new Marionette proxy format:

> [{proxy={"proxyType":"MANUAL","httpProxy":"host.proxy","httpProxyPort":80,"sslProxy":"host.proxy","sslProxyPort":80}}]

No more "proxyHost:proxyPort" format, but httpProxy=host, httpProxyPort=port.

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("proxyType", "MANUAL");
json.addProperty("httpProxy", aHost);
json.addProperty("httpProxyPort", aPort);
json.addProperty("sslProxy", aHost);
json.addProperty("sslProxyPort", aPort);

required.setCapability("proxy", json);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, cap, required);
```

Here is all the code:

```
 import java.io.File;
```

import java.io.IOException;

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class TestProxy
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
    if (args.length == 0)
    {
      System.out.println("usage: IP port");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    String proxyServer = args[0];
    int proxyPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    try
    {
      TestProxy test = new TestProxy();
      test.TestDriver(proxyServer, proxyPort);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }    
  }

  private void TestDriver(String aHost, int aPort) throws IOException
  {
    WebDriver driver = null;
    GeckoDriverService service = null;

    if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX)
    {
      FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/home/ubuntu/firefox/firefox"));

      service = new GeckoDriverService.Builder(firefoxBinary)
          .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/bin/geckodriver"))
          .usingAnyFreePort()
          .usingAnyFreePort()
          .withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("DISPLAY",":20"))
          .build();
      service.start();      
    }
    else if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS)
    {
      FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"));

      service = new GeckoDriverService.Builder(firefoxBinary)
          .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\Windows\\geckodriver.exe"))
          .usingAnyFreePort()
          .usingAnyFreePort()
          .build();
      service.start();      
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Unknown operation system");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    DesiredCapabilities required = new DesiredCapabilities();

    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("proxyType", "MANUAL");
    json.addProperty("httpProxy", aHost);
    json.addProperty("httpProxyPort", aPort);
    json.addProperty("sslProxy", aHost);
    json.addProperty("sslProxyPort", aPort);

    required.setCapability("proxy", json);

    driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, cap, required);

    driver.navigate().to("https://api.ipify.org/?format=text");

    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2963

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/97#issuecomment-255386464